# How to make preg_quote case insensitive?

Tags: php, html, search

I am building a small search engine inside the LAN. Because there are only ~25 pages, I'm using a bash script which takes a list of URLs and formats them into HTML, e.g:

```
<div id="result"><p><a href="#">Title 1</a></p><p>Description 1</p></div>
<div id="result"><p><a href="#">Title 2</a></p><p>Description 2</p></div>
```

Then a PHP script which searches the GET input from each line of the above, and returns each matching line.
My question, how do I make this search case insensitive? My PHP code is as follows:

```
<?php
 // index.php

include('inc/header.html');
  $searchfor = $_GET['q'];

         $file = 'inc/urls.txt';

   $contents = file_get_contents($file);
     $pattern = preg_quote($searchfor, '/');
    $pattern = "/^.*$pattern.*\$/m";

     if(preg_match_all($pattern, $contents, $matches)){
            echo "<p>Found matches:</p>";
       echo implode("<br />", $matches[0]);
      }
       else{
             echo "<p>No matches found.</p>";
        fclose ($file); 
         }
include('inc/footer.html');
?>
```

I know this is probably fairly obvious, and that I'm looking for a /i somewhere around `preg_quote`, but I'm new to PHP and can't seem to find the answer, nor any similar questions on SE/SO/etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try this `$pattern = "/^.*$pattern.*\$/mi";`?